# How to write a function that uses 2 values of another function which generates 10000 values?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I've programmed a linear-congruential generator that prints 10000 pseudo-random values to the terminal. This is part of a module, and thus its own function. I now want to write a new function that takes 2 random uniformally distributed numbers and uses them in the box muller method to generate 2 more numbers. I understand the box muller part itself, I just don't understand how I program it to take just 2 values from the previous 10000? Here's my code:

```
module rng
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
  real(kind=dp) :: A=100, B= 104001, M = 714025 

contains 

function lcg(seed)
  integer :: lcg
  integer, optional, intent(in) :: seed
  real(kind=dp) :: x = 0

  if(present(seed)) x = seed
  x = mod(A * x + B, M)
  lcg = x
end function

end module


program lcgtest
  use rng
  implicit none
  integer :: N


  do N = 1, 10000
    print *, lcg()
  end do
end program
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an exercise? Because for real usage you will find good libraries out there.

Comment: "to take just 2 values from the previous 10000".  Literally you would save the 10000 values in an array.  What criteria do you use to pick the two? and why would you want to do it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function generates 1 integer, not 1000. Just call it two times and you have two numbers.

```
do
  a = lcg ()
  b = lcg ()

  !do something with a and b
end do
```